# TFS check-in local changeset to another project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to check-in a local changeset which has not been checked in to another version in TFS? I have been working on a Stage v2.1 version and now I have to check-in or add my changeset to Stage v.2.2 whithout touching v2.1 (I'm using VS2012)

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen an option such as you describe. I would suggest that you do a manual merge into v2.2 using a file compare tool to see which changes to merge. Once happy that the functionality is working and compiling you change check in v2.2 and undo the changes in v2.1
( I assume that v2.2 is a branch from 2.1 and as such will have its own set of files in your local workspace )

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes I have both of them on my local system, but other developers have worked on v2.2 so if i replace some files we will lose their work. am I wrong?

Comment: yes, I did not intend that you replace the files, you need to compare the files, file by file using a file comparison tool to migrate functionality that you have written in each file to the file from v2.1 into the file from v2.2. So for example if you have writen function XYZ() in file1 of V2.1 you need to copy that function into file1 of v2.2

Comment: if you do not already have a file comparison tool I have used http://winmerge.org/ in the past